# Global average polling without fc layer, Vanishing gradient or other problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, gradient-descent, pytorch

I have built this network with pytorch, it's basically a modification of VGG16, I add some layers and remove some. The output of the network are meant to be softmax scores for **F.multilabel-soft-margin-loss** in pytorch.

```
def __init__(self, bn=False):
super(WSDR, self).__init__()
# Network based on VGG16
# ConvReLU means a conv layer following a relu
self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(ConvReLU(3, 64, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           ConvReLU(64, 64, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           nn.MaxPool2d(2))
self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(ConvReLU(64, 128, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           ConvReLU(128, 128, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           nn.MaxPool2d(2))
self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(ConvReLU(128, 256, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           ConvReLU(256, 256, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           ConvReLU(256, 256, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           nn.MaxPool2d(2))
self.conv4 = nn.Sequential(ConvReLU(256, 512, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           ConvReLU(512, 512, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           ConvReLU(512, 512, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           nn.MaxPool2d(2))
self.conv5 = nn.Sequential(ConvReLU(512, 512, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           ConvReLU(512, 512, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                           ConvReLU(512, 512, 3, pd=True, bn=bn))

self.gap = nn.Sequential(ConvReLU(512, 1024, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                         ConvReLU(1024, 20, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                         nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=14, stride=14))
# adding this fc layer, things go right
# self.fc = nn.Linear(self.num_classes, self.num_classes)

def forward(self, im_data):
    x = self.conv1(im_data)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.conv3(x)
    x = self.conv4(x)
    conv5features = self.conv5(x)
    gap = self.gap(conv5features)
    scores = gap.squeeze()
    # scores = self.fc(scores)
    return scores
```

But this network can not reduce loss correctly. The output of the network become all zeros after only 2 or 3 iterations(one forward and one backward means one iteration), so do the gradients in the network.

I think the problem may be caused by the last global average pooling layer, usually people add another fc layer after that but I didn't. I tried to add a fc, and the problem disappered, the loss start to reduce after adding fc layer.

My question is:

- What caused the vanishing gradient and zero output(gap2 feature, scores in the above code all become zeros)?
- Why adding a fc layer can solve that problem?
- I really don't want the fc layer because I want every channel of the last conv feature to represent one class(for classification), how can I make things right without adding fc layer?

Please leave your advice, any hints would be helpful

Addtional codes:

```
class ConvReLU(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch, kernel_sz, stride=1, relu=True, pd=True, bn=False):
    super(ConvReLU, self).__init__()
    padding = int((kernel_sz - 1) / 2) if pd else 0  # same spatial size by default
    self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, kernel_sz, stride, padding=padding)
    self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch, eps=0.001, momentum=0, affine=True) if bn else None
    self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True) if relu else None

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv(x)
    if self.bn is not None:
        x = self.bn(x)
    if self.relu is not None:
        x = self.relu(x)
    return x

# compute output
output = model(input_var)  # the above model, input_var:image data
loss = F.multilabel_soft_margin_loss(output, target_var)
# compute gradient and do SGD step
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: I kind of find the problem, I removed the ReLU activation layer before the Global Average Pooling layer: change **self.gap = nn.Sequential(ConvReLU(512, 1024, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                         ConvReLU(1024, 20, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                         nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=14, stride=14))** to **self.gap = nn.Sequential(ConvReLU(512, 1024, 3, pd=True, bn=bn),
                         nn.Conv2d(1024, 20, 3, 1, padding=1),
                         nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=14, stride=14))**. And the loss start to change.

Comment: I think the reason that my network died before is that ReLU layer output too many zeros, and stop the output of the network thus the backward path. But  that's just an intuitively thought, maybe someone can explain it more explicitly?